# What's the source of the "new world religion" memorandum signed in Strasbourg?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, religious-education

There is a document which is shared on the internet these days. I saw it in Romanian language and then searching a bit, I found it in English as well: it's a "memorandum" *signed in Strasbourg* containing a list of weird rules which they say they're going to be implemented in different dates in the future.

I quickly read it, but it looks to me like a non-credible thingy. However, I have many friends who tend to believe it. In our country, this appeared on sites I don't trust.

What I'm wondering is if we can find out if this is a credible (at least official/true) document. If not, I'm also wondering if we can find out who created this and what is the source.

Can we do that?

For reference, I will leave here (downloaded from [here](https://www.gloria.tv/text/CL6ssdZ3PMZzRGxyTtPrEXZee)):

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Patriarch Elijah is the Byzantine Greek Patriarch whose patriarchy was instituted in 2011 following a decision of the Ukrainian  Orthodox Greek-Catholic church to separate.    The Memorandum to which he objects may, if genuine, be connected to Accept Pluralism which is connected to the European Union. It was suggested during the referendum on the UK leaving the EU ,that the EU was  pro-secularisation, particularly of education, although it was something of a fringe issue.

Comment: @davidlol Interesting. Do we have any hints/clues if this is genuine or not? Thanks!

Comment: And actually, the above articles are only about education-related stuff. In the Romanian version, there are other sections as well.

Comment: This looks like a parody. If it were official, why would the word [_suicidium_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suicidium) (suicide) be in the title? Why would an official document contain a URL to some random blog ([apokalypsisnow.blogspot.ru](https://apokalypsisnow.blogspot.ru/2015/04/blog-post.html))? It's quite good satire, nevertheless.

Comment: I cant find anything on the Accept Pluralism site about this (not in English anyway)  so that looks like a red herring - based on something I read in a referendum leaflet.  Sorry.. I notice in the third to bottom paragraph the Patriarch (if it is indeed he) says the Memorandum has never been published.- if so does he say how he knows about it, in Romanian?. Has it been put to any of the alleged signatories, politicians and bishops? I suspect there must be something in the Greek press. Re suicidium that seems to be the Patriarch's take on the Memorandum, not the alleged memorandum itself. .

Comment: Suicidal Great Council in Crete
28 June 2016 -- http://vkpatriarhat.org.ua/en/?p=12832 links to earlier page https://web.archive.org/web/20160328171723/http://vkpatriarhat.org.ua/en/?p=12338  The Eighth Pan-Orthodox Council – suicidium /Part 5: Liquidation documents from Strasbourg I/  -- strong language: genocide, spiritual suicide, liquidation

Comment: [This site translated by google](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ro&u=http://www.apologeticum.ro/2016/03/super-memorandumul-si-noua-super-religie-masonica-mondiala-si-biserica-in-perioada-2016-2020/&prev=search) seems to claim the author translated it from the original Greek.  Many hint that it might be a fake because a certain church father, Ephraim/Efram's signature.  Though others argue, haven't many of these things already occurred? and advocate a wait and see -- all of it will come to pass attitude.  The site even has a link to the Greek language original.

Comment: At the risk of spoiling the fun, this looks like obvious bollocks to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document in the question is what is referred to in Wikipedia as 'complete bollocks', i.e. something so far detached from reality as to defy detailed refutation. **The claims made in it are completely false.**

For a look at reality, you can follow [this link to a description of the real Eighth Pan-Orthodox Council](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Orthodox_Council), (which happened in Greece, not Strasbourg) and from there read the official documents in several languages.

Apart from the ridiculousness of some of the claims (such as the abolition of all national holidays, the involvement of the Pope and the EU) many of them were claimed to start in September 2016. This has not happened.